# How can I print the JS function output through an HTML tag like p which has a specific id. I have added the function name in the button

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I have added the function to the button with onclick attribute. when i print the result with console.log or document.write it working nicely. but when i try to print it with an HTML tag. Like document.getElementById('urscore').innerHTML= c; Then it not working?

```js
function check(){
    var c = 0;

    var questionsarea = document.getElementsByClassName('questionarea');
    var option = [document.quize.options1.value, document.quize.options2.value, document.quize.options3.value, document.quize.options4.value, document.quize.options5.value, document.quize.options6.value, document.quize.options7.value, document.quize.options8.value, document.quize.options9.value, document.quize.options10.value];


    for(let i=0; i<questionsarea.length; i++){
       
        if (option[i]==0){
            c+=0;
        }
        else if(option[i]==1){
            c+=1;
        }
        else if(option[i]==2){
            c+=2;
        }
        else {
            c+=3;
        }
    }
   document.write(c);
}
```

Comment: `document.write` expects a string. You're trying to give it a number. That seems like one problem.  Also, the use of the `document.write()` method is strongly discouraged -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: @Josh yes, if the thing that you tell is correct. md yeasin use `document.write(\`${c}\`)`

Comment: @Josh thanks, brothers. But I need to show the function result inside a p tag. How can I do it?

Comment: when you use `document.getElementById('urscore').innerHTML= c` what is the error message in the developer console? What is your html mark up? How is check called?

Comment: Use `number.toString()` to convert your data from a number to a string. Then, add it to some element that's already in the DOM using `innerText` or `innerHTML`. If you don't have any elements (just a blank HTML document), then you can hook into the `<body>` using `document.body.innerText = "some text string"`.

Comment: Source File: https://cutt.ly/xCqN1DO